# How to calculate the integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have only the following integration

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{N}e^{-\int_{b-a}^{b}f\left(x\left(s\right)\right)ds}da$

Is it possible to simplify this integral ? How can I calculate it ? Is it possible to take out some terms from the first sum between $0$ and $N$ ?

As the born of the integral on exponential depends on $a$ on which we sum for the first integral, it looks weird to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt that you can say anything about this expression in the general case. You can try to do some Fubini on it but the result may look even worse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the advice on Fubini.